# Why Is My Event Handler Considered as Having No References?

Tags: uwp, reference

I coded an event handler for a ComboBox's dropDownClosed event:

[image]

...but it show "0 references":

[image]

Why would that be? The button click events do display 1 reference...

Comment: I don't know why, but now it does show 1 reference - although I changed nothing in connection with that event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably because there is no backing field generated for it for one reason or another. This (the backing field in the generated `*.g.cs` file) is where the reference to the event handler comes from.

Either you haven't assigned the `ComboBox` element an `x:Name` in the XAML markup or the element is part of a template rather than being part of the partial page class itself.

Consider the following `ItemsControl` as an example:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cmb" DropDownClosed="cmb_DropDownClosed" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Since the `ComboBox` belongs to a `DataTemplate`, there won't be any backing field generate for it in the code-behind of the page where the `ItemsControl` is defined. This is also why you can't access the `ComboBox` directly using its name ("cmb") in the code-behind.

Comment: It did have an xname: <ComboBox x:Name="cmbxMaptype" ; at any rate, it's working now (without making any changes), and the the event handler code works, too.

Comment: Well, if you put the `ComboBox` in the page itself and do give it an `x:Name` you will get a reference showing up sooner or later.

Comment: Okay, but why is it not immediate?